# can't find executable error autotest 4.4.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, autotest, spork

I'm trying to roll back a failed installation of spork, and uninstalled autotest since I was having problems with it.  Upon reinstall, I am now getting this error when running autotest from the command line:

/opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:335:in `bin_path': can't find executable autotest for autotest-4.4.6 (Gem::Exception)

I've been googling this for a while with no luck ("The rspec, autotest, and Rails 3..." thread's suggestions didn't work.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If autotest has been specified in your `Gemfile` and you've run `bundle install`, then you can run autotest within the context of your bundle:

```
bundle exec autotest
```

Comment: In case someone else hits this problem, what worked for me was, first: running gem cleanup and getting rid of old gems.  Second, adding autotest to me gemfile and running "bundle install," and finally, running bundle exec autotest.

Comment: @TronSawyer That worked for me too - after I'd run `gem cleanup` I didn't even need the `bundle exec` it simply worked from `autotest`